# calls to instanceMethodSignatureForSelector return nil.Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

The Header File of NSString has the function declartion like this:

```
- (instancetype)initWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)len encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
```

Here is the demo code.

```
SEL selector1 = @selector(initWithBytes:length:encoding:);    
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector1]);    
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString new] methodSignatureForSelector:selector1]);
```

But both of the results are: (null). Why? Can any function run without MethodSignature?

The enviroment: XCode6.2 Beta. iPhone Simulator.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a method can run without a method signature, if some other object has the method signature and responds to the method. Basically, you've stumbled onto an implementation detail. NSString does not in fact respond to `initWithBytes:length:encoding:`, as you can discover by asking it:

```
SEL selector1 = @selector(initWithBytes:length:encoding:);
NSLog(@"%d", [[NSString class] instancesRespondToSelector:selector1]); // 0
```

It is presumably being [forwarded dynamically](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html) to a helper object of some other class that you're not supposed to know about. You can use this same feature in your own code.

Comment: Very interesting question. Objective-C messaging is very powerful! It is also possible to _create_ a method that doesn't exist, in code, the first time a message is sent to an object; that is how Core Data `@dynamic` properties work.

Comment: Hi, matt. As you say that the case may be forwarded dynamically to a helper object. So I tried to set one breakpoint using bmessage, like this "bmessage -[NSString forwardInvocation:]". And then test the code "char *pStr = "abcs";NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:pStr length:4 encoding:4]);". But it seems the breakpoint didn't fire. Why?   Do you have any help?  thank you very mush.

Comment: I do not know the exact details. But NSString is much more complicated and subtle than that. The work is not being done by NSString but by the secret class NSPlaceholderString, so your breakpoint is on the wrong class. And NSPlaceholderString does not call `forwardInvocation:` either; it is probably doing this work at a much lower level than Objective-C `forwardInvocation:`, for efficiency.

Comment: Yes, the class "NSPlaceholderString" works. Thank you.